# i want 2008-12-13 10:42:00 show second Minute and date in php

Tags: php

I want 2008-12-13 10:42:00 show second Minute and date in php

```
 $days = floor($row['TimeSpent'] / (60 * 60 * 24));
 $remainder = $row['TimeSpent'] % (60 * 60 * 24);
 $hours = floor($remainder / (60 * 60));
 $remainder = $remainder % (60 * 60);
 $minutes = floor($remainder / 60);
 $seconds = $remainder % 60;

 if($days > 0)
    echo date('F d Y', $row['date_created']);
    elseif($days == 0 && $hours == 0 && $minutes == 0)
    echo "few seconds ago";     
    elseif($days == 0)
    echo $minutes.' minutes ago';
    else
    echo "few seconds ago";
```

Comment: Please use: [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: where?

my date it '2015-04-16 08:29:49'

i want show in second minute and date wise..

Comment: Try it! Just simply try it with the `DateTime` class and add your attempt into your question. Also add a little example of input, current output and what you would expect the output to be

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP DateTime like this:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2008-12-13 10:42:00');
$datetime2 = new DateTime();
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%y years') . "<br>";
echo $interval->format('%m months') . "<br>";
echo $interval->format('%d days') . "<br>";
echo $interval->format('%h hours') . "<br>";
echo $interval->format('%i minutes') . "<br>";
echo $interval->format('%s seconds ago');
```

The output would be something like:

> 6 years
>
> 4 months
>
> 4 days
>
> 6 hours
>
> 32 minutes
>
> 56 seconds ago

Answer (score 0):

This is so common usecase these days so lot of developers have already solved this issue, one of such solution is using php Carbon library found here 
http://carbon.nesbot.com/

with Carbon library installed you can just do it like this

```
echo Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2008-12-13 10:42:00')->diffForHumans();
```

You can find more about this usage here 
http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff

Remember most of the problems we face in development is already solved, so do a little research I am sure you will find good solutions.

Comment: Why does OP need an external library if there are already functions for this in php?

Comment: @Rizier123 he want something that is like facebook like date and time showing like 3 seconds ago or 1 month ago, something like that. So I dont think there is any standared implementation for that in php library. So I think using Carbon is really time saving solution, also if he spend little more time on Carbon documentation, I feel it can be really helpful for his whole project in many places. So I suggested the library :)